# How can I test elements wrapped in an ng-container exist for Angular 6 with Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, ng-container

I am trying to write a unit test to see whether or not elements wrapped in an `<ng-container>` exist, but my tests fails because it seems the elements are created any way.

My code is:

HTML

```
<ng-container *ngIf="router.url === '/login'">
    <div id="login"></div>
</ng-container>
```

Unit Test

```
it('should display the login div when on the login page', fakeAsync(inject([Router], (router: Router) => {
    router.navigate(['/login']);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(debugEl.query(By.css('#login'))).toBeNull();
})));
```

I would prefer not to have to wrap my `<ng-container>` in another element; I have seen a few articles online that say to do this, but is there a way to check elements in an Angular container without having around it?

Thanks!

Comment: `expect(debugEl.query(By.css('#login'))).toBeNull();` does fail, because element with `id="login"` exists. What is your doubt here?

Comment: I may not understand exactly how angular does it, but I thought that if the result of an `*ngIf` was false, angular would not add the elements in a container to the DOM, therefore would not exist.  I have successfully written tests with this understanding in the past, but the difference is that those if statements were in a `<div>` or some other native HTML element.

Comment: You are right, If `*ngIf was false, angular would not add the elements in a container to the DOM, therefore would not exist.`. And the whole purpose of `ng-container` is to eliminate the need of those extra `<div>` which exist only to have the condition. `ng-container` will not be rendered inside the dom, but the content inside it will render if the condition is satisfied.

Comment: Right, so in my unit test I am using a router object to navigate to a page in my app called `login` and the condition is that if the route is login, display the contents of the `ng-container`, but my unit test is not passing.

Comment: Your unit test is not passing because you are checking for `toBeNull()`, which is false. Instead you should be checking something like `expect(debugEl.query(By.css('#login'))).not.toBeNull();` or `expect(debugEl.query(By.css('#login'))).toBeDefined();`

Comment: Does that resolve your issue? Or is there anything else that is causing a problem?

Comment: @Amit Chigadani, That did the trick.  For some tests I needed to check the null, and others it was whether it was defined or not.  Anyway, that's what I was missing.  Thanks.

Comment: Great! I have made an answer with that. Feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments,

Your unit test is not passing because you are checking for `toBeNull()`, which is false. Instead you should be checking something like

```
expect(debugEl.query(By.css('#login'))).not.toBeNull();
```

or

```
expect(debugEl.query(By.css('#login'))).toBeDefined();
```